# WhereIn Inside ->where() array - Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sqlbuilder

I'm trying use a whereIn inside a where array I am passing to Laravel query Builder:

```
$where = [['Participants.Client_Id','IN', $clientId]];

DB::table('Participants')->where($where)->get()
```

Something like is what I want to achieve, and I know there are works around such as using whereIn, but I'm sharing here a small piece of code to give you an idea, so I need to change the array to make it works as a whereIn, not changing the ->where to ->whereIn or ->whereRaw

Answer (score 0):

```
  DB::table('participants)->whereIn('Participants.Client_Id',$clientId)->get();
```

You must collect the IDs in the `$clientId` variables.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for as I explained in my question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you could do something like that :

```php
$wheres = [['Participants.Client_Id','IN', [$clientId]]];

$query = DB::table('Participants');
foreach($wheres as $where) {
    $query->where($where[0], $where[1], $where[2]);
}
$participants = $query->get();
```

Comment: ['Participants.Client_Id','IN', [$clientId]] does not work, it looks like it's not being identified as a whereIn by laravel query builder

Answer (score 0):

As laravel document , you can use array in `where` and each element of this array must be a array with three value . So your `$where` variable is correct.

But as I searched `in` operator is not supported by query builder of where.